# MPChartAndroid - Line chart with multiple dataset

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MpChart library for Android graph representation

Let's say we have DataSet1 and DataSet2. DataSet1  has a list of entries with timestamp as X-value and some Integer as Y-value. Dataset2 has only timestamp as X-value they do not have any Y-value. I want to plot DataSet2's
entry on LineChart which was plotted on DataSet1's entries.

Comment: refer here for solution : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data

Comment: @JeelVankhede Already referred. Didn't find relevant to my case. Can you help me more?

Comment: Can you provide some of your code about what you've done? it's impossible to provide suggestions without looking to code.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.